# How do you add the relative frequency in a Mosaic Plot in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create a **mosaic plot** with an x- and y-axis, where the relative frequency is shown on the y-axis. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Os6M.jpg) is what my plot currently looks like, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auVmp.jpg) is what I want it to look like. I have attached my R code below. Thanks in advance!

```
mosaictable <- matrix (c (3, 9, 22, 21), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
rownames (mosaictable) = c ("White", "Blue ")
colnames (mosaictable) = c ("Captured", "Not Captured")
mosaicplot (t (mosaictable), sub = "Pigeon Color", ylab = "Relative frequency", 
            cex.axis = 1.1, main = "", col = c ("firebrick", "goldenrod1")
            
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can add `axis` like below

```
mosaictable <- matrix(c(3, 9, 22, 21), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
rownames(mosaictable) <- c("White", "Blue ")
colnames(mosaictable) <- c("Captured", "Not Captured")
mosaicplot(mosaictable,
  sub = "Pigeon Color", ylab = "Relative frequency",
  cex.axis = 1.1, main = "", col = c("firebrick", "goldenrod1")
)

axis(1)
axis(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @TylerBrentdeLeon I found that `prop.table` is not necessary. You just need to add `axis(1)` and `axis(4)`